# SQL Many-To-Many within a One-To-Many fetch

Tags: sql, join

I have a table Table A that has a one-to-many relation with Table B. This Table B has a many-to-many relation with Table C and another many-to-many relation with Table D using a join table. Now I have an id for Table A that I want to use to fetch Table B with all its joins. Is this a subquery of a simple select would be sufficient?

```
SELECT 
  tableB.id, 
  tableC.id, 
  tableD.id 
from 
  TableB tableB
LEFT JOIN TableC tableC ON tableB.id = tableC.id
LEFT JOIN TableD tableD ON tableB.id = tableD.id 
where
  tableB.tableAId = :id
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Ok I corrected my query!

Comment: Post sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would join. If you want A in your results then:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
from a
join b on b.id_a = a.id_a
left join bc on bc.id_b = b.id_b -- bridge table b <-> c
left join c on c.id_c = bc.id_c
left join bd on bd.id_b = b.id_b -- bridge table b <-> d
left join d on d.id_d = bd.id_b
where a.id = ?
```

If you don't want A in your results then:

```
select b.*, c.*, d.*
from b 
left join bc on bc.id_b = b.id_b
left join c on c.id_c = bc.id_c
left join bd on bd.id_b = b.id_b
left join d on d.id_d = bd.id_b
where b.id_a = ?
```

If you only want Bs with at least one matching C and D, then use inner joins instead of the outer joins.